# How to make Twitter style profile screen in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using the expo managed workflow with React Native. I am trying to design a profile screen that is similar to Twitter. Twitter has four categories on its profile ("Tweets", "Tweets & replies", "Media", and "Likes"). My profile has two. In order to allow the ability to horizontally scroll between categories I have a horizontal ScrollView below the top part of the profile. In the horizontal ScrollView I have two vertical FlatLists (one for each category). I have all of this in a vertical ScrollView so that the top part of the profile scrolls off the page when you scroll. This is the problem: I have a vertical FlatList in a vertical ScrollView which doesn't work for what I want. Does anyone know how I can work around this?

Comment: It seems like you are looking for a top tabs navigator. Here's one from [@react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/)

Comment: I don't think that this addresses the problem of their being a vertical FlatList nested in a vertical ScrollView.

Comment: I just tested it and it doesn't do what I want.

Comment: It sounds like the use of the nested scrollview FlatList was to get the Twitter like navigation. I suggested the top tab navigator because it would all together avoid having to implement your own navigator

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/QL8Y-X_O4